# Script to change PHP version

Tags: bash

I'm trying code a bash script to swith between php version, but I'm getting the following message error:

```
Which PHP version would you like to enable?
php5.6
Module php5.6 already disabled
Module php7.1 already disabled
Module php7.2 already disabled
Enabling... 
ERROR: Module  does not exist!
```

My code:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Which PHP version would you like to enable?";

read $version;

sudo a2dismod php5.6;
sudo a2dismod php7.1;
sudo a2dismod php7.2;

echo "Enabling...";
sudo a2enmod "$version";

systemctl restart apache2;
```

Comment: Run `bash -x yourscript` -- logging each command as it runs -- and see what the `sudo a2enmod` command is actually doing. Then compare that to what you *expect* it to do, and what that command does if you invoke it by hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to remove `$` from `read $version`.

Do not use `$` when assigning content to a variable.

Comment: Why? (Obviously we know, *but OP doesn't*, so please elaborate)